# Can this be optimized further?

Tags: mysql, optimization, profiling, query-optimization

I have this query

```
select counterparty_id, max(id) max_id from client_administrations where counterparty_type = 1 and effective_on <= '2013-10-22' group by counterparty_id
```

When I explain this query it gives me

> ********************* 1. row ***************************
>              id: 1
>     select_type: SIMPLE
>           table: client_administrations
>            type: index
>   possible_keys: NULL
>             key: cec
>         key_len: 11
>             ref: NULL
>            rows: 234969
>           Extra: Using where; Using index
>   1 row in set (0.00 sec)

this query returns 2,34,630 rows which takes 0.18 seconds to run. But the problem is this query is used many times in a given functionality and the rows in the database might go upto 10 lakhs even. That is my concern. I tried profiling for this

> mysql> show profile for query 1;
>   +----------------------+----------+
>   | Status               | Duration |
>   +----------------------+----------+
>   | starting             | 0.000126 |
>   | checking permissions | 0.000018 |
>   | Opening tables       | 0.000032 |
>   | System lock          | 0.000016 |
>   | init                 | 0.000051 |
>   | optimizing           | 0.000029 |
>   | statistics           | 0.000145 |
>   | preparing            | 0.000047 |
>   | executing            | 0.000010 |
>   | Sorting result       | 0.000009 |
>   | **Sending data         | 0.117429** |
>   | end                  | 0.000024 |
>   | query end            | 0.000007 |
>   | closing tables       | 0.000012 |
>   | freeing items        | 0.000016 |
>   | logging slow query   | 0.000004 |
>   | cleaning up          | 0.000005 |
>   +----------------------+----------+

This shows sending data takes maximum amount of time. The RAM size in my localhost is 3GG and in server it is 32 GB. Even this does not make any difference in the time taken for query to execute. Its not only for this query but there are several queries in my database which inspite of having index in the "extra" column of explain the maximum time is taken in sending data of profiling. I did change some global variables. Here is the default setting of my global variables

> mysql> show variables like "%cache%";
>   +------------------------------+----------------------+
>   | Variable_name                | Value                |
>   +------------------------------+----------------------+
>   | binlog_cache_size            | 32768                |
>   | binlog_stmt_cache_size       | 32768                |
>   | have_query_cache             | YES                  |
>   | key_cache_age_threshold      | 300                  |
>   | key_cache_block_size         | 1024                 |
>   | key_cache_division_limit     | 100                  |
>   | max_binlog_cache_size        | 18446744073709547520 |
>   | max_binlog_stmt_cache_size   | 18446744073709547520 |
>   | metadata_locks_cache_size    | 1024                 |
>   | query_cache_limit            | 1048576              |
>   | query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096                 |
>   | query_cache_size             | 16777216             |
>   | query_cache_type             | ON                   |
>   | query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF                  |
>   | stored_program_cache         | 256                  |
>   | table_definition_cache       | 400                  |
>   | table_open_cache             | 400                  |
>   | thread_cache_size            | 8                    |
>   +------------------------------+----------------------+

Can something be done to help this "sending data " part.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: if you need to use same 234969 rows so frequent - it is something very wrong with architecture and looks like lack of caching

Comment: Yeah I believe so too. But unfortunately the application is big and flow changes will require lot of time right now. So architecture can't be changed right now